# Aligned function

Tags: align

how can I have this effect? here is my code

```
\[\textcolor{blue}{
\begin{aligned}
u_{1}^{\prime} &=u_{1} \\
u_{2}^{\prime} &=u_{2}-\frac{\left\langle u_{2}, u_{1}^{\prime}\right\rangle}{\left\langle u_{1}^{\prime}, u_{1}^{\prime}\right\rangle} u_{1}^{\prime} \\
u_{3}^{\prime} &=u_{3}-\frac{\left\langle u_{3}, u_{1}^{\prime}\right\rangle}{\left\langle u_{1}^{\prime}, u_{1}^{\prime}\right\rangle} u_{1}^{\prime}-\frac{\left\langle u_{3}, u_{2}^{\prime}\right\rangle}{\left\langle u_{2}^{\prime}, u_{2}^{\prime}\right\rangle} u_{2}^{\prime} \\
\vdots\quad  & \vdots \quad \quad \vdots\\
u_{n}^{\prime} &=u_{n}-\frac{\left\langle u_{n}, u_{1}^{\prime}\right\rangle}{\left\langle u_{1}^{\prime}, u_{1}^{\prime}\right\rangle} u_{1}^{\prime}-\frac{\left\langle u_{n}, u_{2}^{\prime}\right\rangle}{\left\langle u_{2}^{\prime}, u_{2}^{\prime}\right\rangle} u_{2}^{\prime}-\cdots-\frac{\left\langle u_{n}, u_{n-1}^{\prime}\right\rangle}{\left\langle u_{n-1}^{\prime}, u_{n-1}^{\prime}\right\rangle} u_{n-1}^{\prime}
\end{aligned}}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, Gram-Schmidt!!!

Comment: Hahaha yes strugglying with this subject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by removing all `\left` and `\right` that do nothing useful.

Next, define a shorthand for the repeating parts (with parameters).
You can also use `'` instead of `^{\prime}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[\color{blue!70}
\newcommand{\gs}[2]{%
  \frac{\langle u_{#1},u_{#2}'\rangle}
       {\langle u_{#2}',u_{#2}'\rangle}%
  u_{#2}'%
}
\begin{aligned}
u_{1}' &=u_{1} \\
u_{2}' &=u_{2}-\gs{2}{1} \\
u_{3}' &=u_{3}-\gs{3}{1}-\gs{3}{2} \\
\vdotswithin{u_{n}} & \vdotswithin{=} \vdotswithin{u_2-\gs{2}{1}}\\
u_{n}' &=u_{n}-\gs{n}{1}-\gs{n}{2}-\dots-\gs{n}{n-1}
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that (a) uses `\tfrac` instead of `\frac` and (b) uses `\shortvdotswithin` -- a macro provided by the `mathtools` package -- instead of `\vdots` to create a compact-looking system of equations.

Observe that this solution uses but one set of vertical dots between the final two rows. If the equations are typeset too compactly for your taste, just replace `\tfrac` with `\frac` and `\shortvdotswithin` with `\vdotswithin`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{xcolor}     % for '\color' macro
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for '\shortvdotswithin' macro
\newcommand\myfrac[2]{% % handy shortcut macro
    \tfrac{\langle u^{}_{#1}, u_{#2}'\rangle}% % note the use of "^{}"
          {\langle u_{#2}',   u_{#2}'\rangle} 
      u_{#2}'}
    
\begin{document}

\begingroup % limit the scope of the following instruction
\color{blue}
\begin{align*}
u_1' &= u_1 \\
u_2' &= u_2-\myfrac{2}{1} \\
u_3' &= u_3-\myfrac{3}{1}-\myfrac{3}{2} \\
&\shortvdotswithin{=}
u_n' &= u_n-\myfrac{n}{1}-\myfrac{n}{2}-\dots-\myfrac{n}{n-1}
\end{align*}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```